# Install font in latex results in invisible text when compiling with 'latex'

Tags: latex, fonts, installation

I tried installing the nimbus font (http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/psfonts/urwvf/) in my local texmf tree by following the README provided with the package (and also on the website above). However, after installing and using the package, all characters are invisible in my document when I use 'latex' to compile the document. When I use 'pdflatex' it works. What could be the reason for it, not working with 'latex'?